# ImportError: libarrow.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory | python

Tags: python-3.x, shared-libraries, shared, pyarrow, libhdfs

I am getting below error when I am trying to install below library using File (.tar.bz2) . I dont have Internet connection in my hadoop cluster that is the reason I am using below command to install pyarrow using conda.

```
(base) [XXXX@XXX-XXX-XXX goel]# conda install pyarrow-0.14.1-py37h8b68381_2.tar.bz2
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(base) [XXXX@XXX-XXX-XXX goel]#
```

When I try to import I am getting below below error

```
(base) [XXXX@XXX-XXX-XXX usr]# python -c "import pyarrow"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
ImportError: libarrow.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Below are the conda list output:

```
 (base) [XXXX@XXX-XXX-XXX usr]# conda list
    WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
    # packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3:
    #
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
    alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
    anaconda                  2019.03                  py37_0
    anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
    anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0
    anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0
    arrow                     0.15.3                   py37_0    <unknown>
    arrow-cpp                 0.15.0           py37h090bef1_2    <unknown>
    asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
    astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0
    astropy                   3.1.2            py37h7b6447c_0
    atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
    attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1
    babel                     2.6.0                    py37_0
    backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
    backports                 1.0                      py37_1
    backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0
    backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
    beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1
    bitarray                  0.8.3            py37h14c3975_0
    bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
    blas                      1.0                         mkl
    bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
    blosc                     1.15.0               hd408876_0
    bokeh                     1.0.4                    py37_0
    boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
    bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h035aef0_1
    bzip2                     1.0.6                h14c3975_5
    ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0
    cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3
    certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0
    cffi                      1.12.2           py37h2e261b9_1
    chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
    click                     7.0                      py37_0
    cloudpickle               0.8.0                    py37_0
    clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
    colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
    conda                     4.6.11                   py37_0
    conda-build               3.17.8                   py37_0
    conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
    conda-verify              3.1.1                    py37_0
    contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0
    cryptography              2.6.1            py37h1ba5d50_0
    curl                      7.64.0               hbc83047_2
    cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
    cython                    0.29.6           py37he6710b0_0
    cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py37h14c3975_1
    dask                      1.1.4                    py37_1
    dask-core                 1.1.4                    py37_1
    dbus                      1.13.6               h746ee38_0
    decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1
    defusedxml                0.5.0                    py37_1
    distributed               1.26.0                   py37_1
    docutils                  0.14                     py37_0
    entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
    et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
    expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0
    fastcache                 1.0.2            py37h14c3975_2
    filelock                  3.0.10                   py37_0
    flask                     1.0.2                    py37_1
    fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0
    freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1
    fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0
    future                    0.17.1                   py37_0
    get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0
    gevent                    1.4.0            py37h7b6447c_0
    glib                      2.56.2               hd408876_0
    glob2                     0.6                      py37_1
    gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1
    gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h10f8cd9_2
    graphite2                 1.3.13               h23475e2_0
    greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h7b6447c_0
    gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1
    gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1
    h5py                      2.9.0            py37h7918eee_0
    harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0
    hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0
    hdfs3                     0.3.1                    py37_0    <unknown>
    heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2
    html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
    icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1
    idna                      2.8                      py37_0
    imageio                   2.5.0                    py37_0
    imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
    importlib_metadata        0.8                      py37_0
    intel-openmp              2019.3                      199
    ipykernel                 5.1.0            py37h39e3cac_0
    ipython                   7.4.0            py37h39e3cac_0
    ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
    ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py37_0
    isort                     4.3.16                   py37_0
    itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
    jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0
    jdcal                     1.4                      py37_0
    jedi                      0.13.3                   py37_0
    jeepney                   0.4                      py37_0
    jinja2                    2.10                     py37_0
    jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2
    jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0
    jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
    jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0
    jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
    jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0
    jupyterlab                0.35.4           py37hf63ae98_0
    jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0
    keras                     2.2.5                    py36_1    file:///opt/custom-conda-channel
    keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0
    kiwisolver                1.0.1            py37hf484d3e_0
    krb5                      1.16.1               h173b8e3_7
    lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py37h14c3975_2
    libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5
    libcurl                   7.64.0               h20c2e04_2
    libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0
    libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4
    libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1
    libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0
    libhdfs3                  2.3.0                         2    <unknown>
    liblief                   0.9.0                h7725739_2
    libpng                    1.6.36               hbc83047_0
    libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0
    libssh2                   1.8.0                h1ba5d50_4
    libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1
    libtiff                   4.0.10               h2733197_2
    libtool                   2.4.6                h7b6447c_5
    libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2
    libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1
    libxml2                   2.9.9                he19cac6_0
    libxslt                   1.1.33               h7d1a2b0_0
    llvmlite                  0.28.0           py37hd408876_0
    locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
    lxml                      4.3.2            py37hefd8a0e_0
    lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0
    lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2
    markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h7b6447c_0
    matplotlib                3.0.3            py37h5429711_0
    mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
    mistune                   0.8.4            py37h7b6447c_0
    mkl                       2019.3                      199
    mkl-service               1.1.2            py37he904b0f_5
    mkl_fft                   1.0.10           py37ha843d7b_0
    mkl_random                1.0.2            py37hd81dba3_0
    more-itertools            6.0.0                    py37_0
    mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1
    mpfr                      4.0.1                hdf1c602_3
    mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
    msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37hfd86e86_1
    multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
    navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
    nbconvert                 5.4.1                    py37_3
    nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
    ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1
    networkx                  2.2                      py37_1
    nltk                      3.4                      py37_1
    nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
    notebook                  5.7.8                    py37_0
    numba                     0.43.1           py37h962f231_0
    numexpr                   2.6.9            py37h9e4a6bb_0
    numpy                     1.16.2           py37h7e9f1db_0
    numpy-base                1.16.2           py37hde5b4d6_0
    numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py37_0
    olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
    openpyxl                  2.6.1                    py37_1
    openssl                   1.1.1b               h7b6447c_1
    packaging                 19.0                     py37_0
    pandas                    0.24.2           py37he6710b0_0
    pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
    pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
    pango                     1.42.4               h049681c_0
    parso                     0.3.4                    py37_0
    partd                     0.3.10                   py37_1
    patchelf                  0.9                  he6710b0_3
    path.py                   11.5.0                   py37_0
    pathlib2                  2.3.3                    py37_0
    patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
    pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0
    pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
    pexpect                   4.6.0                    py37_0
    pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
    pillow                    5.4.1            py37h34e0f95_0
    pip                       19.0.3                   py37_0
    pixman                    0.38.0               h7b6447c_0
    pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
    pluggy                    0.9.0                    py37_0
    ply                       3.11                     py37_0
    prometheus_client         0.6.0                    py37_0
    prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0
    psutil                    5.6.1            py37h7b6447c_0
    ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0
    py                        1.8.0                    py37_0
    py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h7725739_2
    pyarrow                   0.14.1           py37h8b68381_2    <unknown>
    pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
    pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h14c3975_0
    pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
    pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h14c3975_9
    pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37h1ba5d50_0
    pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
    pygments                  2.3.1                    py37_0
    pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0
    pyodbc                    4.0.26           py37he6710b0_0
    pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
    pyparsing                 2.3.1                    py37_0
    pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2
    pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37h7b6447c_0
    pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0
    pytables                  3.5.1            py37h71ec239_0
    pytest                    4.3.1                    py37_0
    pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
    pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
    pytest-doctestplus        0.3.0                    py37_0
    pytest-openfiles          0.3.2                    py37_0
    pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0
    python                    3.7.3                h0371630_0
    python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0
    python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py37_6
    pytz                      2018.9                   py37_0
    pywavelets                1.0.2            py37hdd07704_0
    pyyaml                    5.1              py37h7b6447c_0
    pyzmq                     18.0.0           py37he6710b0_0
    qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
    qtawesome                 0.5.7                    py37_1
    qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py37_0
    qtpy                      1.7.0                    py37_1
    readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5
    requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0
    rope                      0.12.0                   py37_0
    ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h14c3975_0
    scikit-image              0.14.2           py37he6710b0_0
    scikit-learn              0.20.3           py37hd81dba3_0
    scipy                     1.2.1            py37h7c811a0_0
    seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0
    secretstorage             3.1.1                    py37_0
    send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
    setuptools                40.8.0                   py37_0
    simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
    singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
    sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0
    six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
    snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3
    snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py37_0
    sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0
    sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
    soupsieve                 1.8                      py37_0
    sphinx                    1.8.5                    py37_0
    sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
    sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py37_1
    spyder                    3.3.3                    py37_0
    spyder-kernels            0.4.2                    py37_0
    sqlalchemy                1.3.1            py37h7b6447c_0
    sqlite                    3.27.2               h7b6447c_0
    statsmodels               0.9.0            py37h035aef0_0
    sympy                     1.3                      py37_0
    tblib                     1.3.2                    py37_0
    tensorflow                1.13.2               h76b4ce7_0    <unknown>
    terminado                 0.8.1                    py37_1
    testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
    tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0
    toolz                     0.9.0                    py37_0
    tornado                   6.0.2            py37h7b6447c_0
    tqdm                      4.31.1                   py37_1
    traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
    unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
    unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0
    urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0
    wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
    webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
    werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0
    wheel                     0.33.1                   py37_0
    widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py37_0
    wrapt                     1.11.1           py37h7b6447c_0
    wurlitzer                 1.0.2                    py37_0
    xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
    xlsxwriter                1.1.5                    py37_0
    xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
    xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4
    yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2
    zeromq                    4.3.1                he6710b0_3
    zict                      0.1.4                    py37_0
    zipp                      0.3.3                    py37_1
    zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
    zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Updated pyarrow and arrow to 0.15

```
(base1) [XXXX@XXX-XXX-XXX goel]# conda list arrow
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda2/envs/base1:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
arrow                     0.15.3                   py37_0    <unknown>
arrow-cpp                 0.15.0           py37h090bef1_2    <unknown>
pyarrow                   0.15.1           py37h8b68381_0    <unknown>
```

Updated Error Result:

```
(base1) [XXXX@XXX-XXX-XXX goel]# python -c "import pyarrow"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/base1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
**ImportError: libglog.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

**Note:** I can see it looks like issue with the shared object file path.

Thanks in Advance,

Goel

Comment: Can you paste the output of `conda list`?

Comment: Added conda list output in the Question above. Kindly help

Comment: From the error it looks like it is not able to shared object file path. Can you help me how to create and point it in conda.

Comment: @UweL.Korn ... Kindly let me know if you can help with this.

Answer (score 4):

You have installed pyarrow=0.14.1 while arrow-cpp=0.15.0. The versions of these libraries need to be the same.

Comment: Made the required changes stil not working for me. Added new output in the Question.

Comment: **Note:** I can see it looks like issue with the shared object file path.

Comment: You are now missing `glog`. I would strongly suggest to install directly from conda-forge and not using downloaded packages. If this has to happen without internet access, create the environment in the outside and copy it in using conda-pack.